# android urlconnection forces ssl

Tags: android, android-networking

I am trying to connect to a server on port 8080 but AndroidHttpClient is forcing everything not on 8080 to use SSL.  The offending code

```
    URL url = new URL("http", "google.com", 8080, "");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

    urlConnection.connect();
```

and this from Charles log.

[image]

note the URL field is using "https://"

now when I change the port to 80:

```
URL url = new URL("http", "google.com", 80, "");
HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");

urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");

urlConnection.connect();
```

everything works fine:
[image]

I have no idea why it forces it to SSL when not on port 80.  I had a similar issue with AndroidHttClient as well as DefaultHttpClient.  Seems to be an issue with Android.

Comment: did u try HTTPPost or HttpGet as like HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(
"URl");

Comment: yes, tried AndroidHttpClient as well as DefaultHttpClient with "new HttpGet(myUri);"